# Linq to SQL Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

DDL for Database Tables:

```
    Users:
    id - int - identity
    name - varchar - unique

    PCs:
    id - int - idnetity
    name - varchar - unique
    userid - FK to Users

    Apps:
    id - int - identity
    name - varchar
    pcid - FK to PCs
```

I created a DataContext using the Linq To SQL designer in Visual Studio 2008.

I want to perform this query:

```
select
  users.name,
  pcs.name,
  apps.name
from
  users u
  join pcs p on p.userid = u.id
  join apps a on a.pcid = p.id
```

I was told in another thread where I posted an answer that the following was incorrect and that it created a cross-join.

```
var query = from u in db.Users // gets all users
        from p in u.PCs // gets all pcs for user
        from a in p.Apps // gets all apps for pc
        select new
        {
            username = u.Name,
            pcname = p.Name,
            appname = a.Name
        };
```

When I execute this query I get the correct results.  A cross-join with two records in each table should return 8 records but my query correctly returns the two records.

Am I lucky, or is the person telling me that I'm wrong confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will work. It's normal because the second "from" inquires in the PC's set of the users and the third "from", the Apps set of the pcs. And I guess that is not going generate a cross join as T-Sql, because the conditions are already defined in the foreign keys and associations.

But I guess this should be the syntactically you want by inner join;

```
var query = from u in db.Users
            join p in db.PCs on p.UserId == u.Id
            join a in db.Apps on a.PCId == p.Id
            select new
            {
                username = u.Name,
                pcname = p.Name,
                appname = a.Name
            };
```

Answer (score 2):

Jason - I had missed the fact that you were using the built-in Linq to SQL relationships.  Sorry for the misunderstanding; under normal circumstances what you have proposed here will work just fine.

Comment: And before someone asks...  the "abnormal circumstances" would be that the OP in the other thread indicated that he does not use FKs, which is another issue entirely.

Comment: AH, well I guess we both misread, as I missed the part about no foreign keys.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine to me, I'm not sure why that would create a cross join

Comment: Thanks Glenn.  It's late, just wanted to make sure I wasn't insane.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282791/c-operator-in-linq-query#282875